# How to handle background jobs in "Cloud Run" when new instance is created immediately?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scheduled-tasks, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I have a FastAPI project in Cloud Run and it has some background jobs inside it. (Not heavy stuff)

However, when a new instance is being created by Cloud Run due to number of requests etc. every instance runs the background job concurrently.

For example;

I have a task that creates some invoices for customers in the background and if three instances is created immediately, three invoices will be created.

I researched about "FOR UPDATE" usage in PostgreSQL etc. It seems like I can solve by modifying my database but I just wonder if it can be solved in Cloud's side.

- I **don't want** to limit the max. number of instances to 1

What would you do in this situation?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The current answer is very good. But I'm also wondering if your design is good. Performing background process with Cloud Run is an anti-pattern (or to use with caution). Maybe, another Cloud Run services dedicated to that "background" processes, but becoming "frontground" processing because you decoupled the first part to the second with async product, like PubSub or Cloud Task. In summery, don't mix realtime and batch processes on the same environment.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you:) I have re designed my background tasks like a http route and started using Google Scheduler. Now it is much more efficient, even though multiple revision created suddenly, only one of them decides to process the scheduler request. I will research about more how to seperate my background tasks from my main environment. Also I have changed my database, when the scheduler requests I just put a status to some tables and check it in every request. So even if scheduler performs a request and its still processing, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can potentially have N instances of a job (because you don't want to set the max limit to 1), you need to implement your jobs in an idempotent way. Broadly speaking, you have a few ways to achieve idempotency:

1. by enforcing a **business constraint**.
2. by storing an **idempotency key**.
3. by using the **Etag HTTP response header**.

For example, Stripe lets you define an idempotency key for all of your API requests. Stripe stores this key on its servers, and when you make a POST request with the same payload of a previous one, Stripe returns you the same result. POST requests are not idempotent, but using this "trick" they become idempotent.

> Stripe's idempotency works by saving the resulting status code and body of the first request made for any given idempotency key, regardless of whether it succeeded or failed. Subsequent requests with the same key return the same result, including 500 errors.
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests

Tip: you could expand your question by clarifying how these background tasks are created, and where they run.

Comment: My background tasks are just a simple asyncio tasks. I have re-designed them as a route and started using Google Scheduler. Now Scheduler performs request every X minutes and even though unexpected instances are created, only one of them process the request. I also changed my database to check if the process is done just by adding a status id in some tables. So even though scheduler performs request but if the previous request is still processing, it just skips the request. (Like a idempotency key) I dont know if its the best way but I managed to fix it like this. Thank you, it taught me alot!

Comment: You're welcome. If your app needs to perform some long-running task but you want to return a response to the client immediately (e.g. you need to generate a PDF file that takes a few seconds to create), also have a look at Cloud Tasks. It's a distributed job queue. Basically you would use it in place of stuff like Celery for Python or BullMQ for Node.js.